# UIWebview and powerpoint divider issue

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, powerpoint

Ideally I would like to load my ppt and pdf documents into a webview without borders or dividers.  I don't believe this is possible. So this question addresses handling the divider in a ppt document gracefully.

I am attempting to scroll through a ppt making my own paging. I have tried this using the built in paging of the webview's scrollview, but that didn't work. It is difficult to calculate the divider height and the divider will always be present using this approach.

Currently I am testing with a 31 page slideshow.  Occasionally some of the divider shows on the top of the webview. (On the 15th, 24th, 25th, and 26th page)

The pptx has aspect ratio 16x9.  My webview is 1024x576 and I am assuming that is the size of a slide within the webview.

I calculate the divider size as follows.

The height of the document when loaded is 18069.
18069/576 ~ 31.369  This means there are 31 pages.
I calculate the amount of space taken up by dividers as follows: 18069-(31*576) = 213.
Then 213/30 = 7.1 is the divider height.

I am very confused as to the divider height being a decimal. Further, I am confused as to why in the 31 page example, that pages 15,24,25,26 are the ones that don't line up properly.

Sorry for what seemed like a question directed at a specific size thus far, but here is my  code to handle the page down action for dynamically sized documents.

```
- (void)handlePptSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  //swipe up means scroll down
  CGSize pptSize = pptWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
  float y = pptSize.height;
  int pages = y/pptWebView.frame.size.height;
  float diff = pptSize.height - pages*pptWebView.frame.size.height;
  float divider = diff/(pages-1);

  CGPoint cOffset = pptWebView.scrollView.contentOffset;
  float temp = pptScrollOffset + pptWebView.frame.size.height+divider;
  if (temp+pptWebView.frame.size.height <= pptWebView.scrollView.contentSize.height)  {
    pptScrollOffset = temp;
  }
  CGRect visibleRect = CGRectMake(cOffset.x, pptScrollOffset, pptWebView.frame.size.width, pptWebView.frame.size.height);
  [pptWebView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:visibleRect animated:YES];

  NSLog(@"content width %f\ncontent height %f\npages %d\ndiff %f\ndivider %f\npptScrollOffset %f",pptWebView.scrollView.contentSize.width,y,pages,diff,divider,pptScrollOffset);
}
```

Here is an example of the output after scrolling one page

```
content width 1024.000000
content height 18069.000000
pages 31
diff 213.000000
divider 7.100000
pptScrollOffset 583.099976
```

Comment: This will probably end in failure or a complicated mess.  UIWebView has extremely complex view hierarchies and underlying drawing methods.  I'd probably shop around for a powerpoint viewer that doesn't use UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I read a similar thing on other page.

I can't find the page now...so, I just put the code that can get the size of the slide.

This is the code:

```
NSString *w=[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function x(){var rtn='';for (var i=1;i<document.all.length;i++){var a=document.all[i];if (((a.clientWidth>0)&&(a.clientHeight>0))&&(a.scrollHeight.toString()==a.offsetHeight.toString())&&(a.offsetHeight.toString()==a.clientHeight.toString())){return ''+a.offsetWidth; }}return rtn;};x();"];
NSString *h=[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function x(){var rtn='';for (var i=1;i<document.all.length;i++){var a=document.all[i];if (((a.clientWidth>0)&&(a.clientHeight>0))&&(a.scrollHeight.toString()==a.offsetHeight.toString())&&(a.offsetHeight.toString()==a.clientHeight.toString())){return ''+a.offsetHeight; }}return rtn;};x();"];
```

Then scroll the webView

```
NSString* javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollBy(0, %@);", h];   
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

This sample didn't count the borders. Just put them in, I think it will be perfect~~